# Peer Eval Question about open and closed functions and sets

Tags: real-analysis

As part of my intro to real analysis course, I have to evaluate my peers' proofs. The question I'm not sure about asks the solver to

> Give examples of each of the following. You do not need to justify your claims. Find a continuous function $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ whose range is:
>
> i. a bounded open interval
>
> $$f:(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \sin (x). $$
> ii. a closed and bounded interval
>
> $$f:(0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \sin (x). $$
>
> iii. an open and unbounded interval
>
> $$f:(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \tan (x). $$
>
> iv. a closed and unbounded interval.
>
> $$f:(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \tan (x). $$
> The answers my classmate added are still within the text, but the ones I'm really not sure about are iii and iv. Since it's the same function with the same domain and range, would it not mean that he is saying that function is both open and closed? And is so, at least one of them has to be false since we know that only the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ are both open and closed. I believe part iv is true, but I'm just not sure if I'm making this harder on myself than need be or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The range of the function $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which is both open and closed as you stated.

Comment: So both iii and iv are okay as is?

Comment: Yes, both are correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought I was making this harder on myself that it actually was.

Comment: Your peer has been overthinking (i) -- any $(a,b)$ and $f(x)=x$ would have worked. And for (ii) any constant function provided you accept $[y,y]$ as closed bounded interval. The *intended* solutions for (iii) and (iv) *may* have been something like $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto \frac1x$ and $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto \frac1x+x^2$, but the examples given are all valiud.